# rails error with tests after adding before_filter :login_required to the controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, before-filter

I added the **before_filter** to my controllers to require a login of the user.

Here's an example of my Unit Controller with the added **before_filter**:

```
class UnitsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :login_required

  def index
    @units = Unit.all
  end

  def show
    @unit = Unit.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @unit = Unit.new
  end
 ...
```

When executing the tests with **rake test**, I get different error messages.

To show you my errors, I only executed the unit controller test with the following line:
ruby -Itest test/functional/units_controller_test.rb

I get the folowing errors:

```
Loaded suite test/functional/units_controller_test
Started
FEFFFEFFF

  1) Failure:
test_create_invalid(UnitsControllerTest) [test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:34]:
expecting <"new"> but rendering with <"">

  2) Error:
test_create_valid(UnitsControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"units"}
    test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:40:in `test_create_valid'

  3) Failure:
test_destroy(UnitsControllerTest) [test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:63]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/units> but was a redirect to     <http://test.host/login>.

  4) Failure:
test_edit(UnitsControllerTest) [test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:45]:
expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <"">

  5) Failure:
test_index(UnitsControllerTest) [test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:17]:
expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">

  6) Error:
test_new(UnitsControllerTest):
NoMethodError: undefined method `login_as' for test_new 
(UnitsControllerTest):UnitsControllerTest
test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:26:in `test_new'

  7) Failure:
test_show(UnitsControllerTest) [test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:22]:
expecting <"show"> but rendering with <"">

  8) Failure:
test_update_invalid(UnitsControllerTest) [test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:51]:
expecting <"edit"> but rendering with <"">

  9) Failure:
test_update_valid(UnitsControllerTest) [test/functional/units_controller_test.rb:57]:
    Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/units/298486374> but was a redirect to <http://test.host/login>.

Finished in 1.50476625 seconds.

9 tests, 9 assertions, 7 failures, 2 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

5.98 tests/s, 5.98 assertions/s
```

If I delete the ***before_filter :login_required** line from the unit controller, the test will be executed without any errors.

I tried to find a solution for that problem, but I could not find any during the last two days.
Please give me advice to solve that problem.

#### Update:

I have a **controller_authentication.rb** file in my /lib directory. The content of the file is as follows:

```
module ControllerAuthentication
  def self.included(controller)
    controller.send :helper_method, :current_user, :logged_in?, :redirect_to_target_or_default
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end

  def logged_in?
    current_user
  end

  def login_required
    unless logged_in?
      store_target_location
      redirect_to login_url, :alert => "You must first log in or sign up before accessing this page."
    end
  end

  def redirect_to_target_or_default(default, *args)
    redirect_to(session[:return_to] || default, *args)
    session[:return_to] = nil
  end

  private

  def store_target_location
    session[:return_to] = request.url
  end
end
```

Do you have any idea, how I have to change the tests to execute them without errors? The tests have to authenticate for the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are requiring authentication to access the controller actions, your tests also need to be authenticated.

It looks like you are using RESTfulAuthentication, in your lib directory there should be an `authenticated_test_helper.rb` providing methods for setting the appropriate session variable to authenticate your tests.